# Program type already present: dagger.Reusable (Firebase InAppMessaging)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I added this in my gradle build:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1'
```

Then I got this error (never appeared before) :

> Program type already present: dagger.Reusable Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present: dagger.Reusable, sources=[Unknown
>   source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Here's my graddle build:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
//implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.32.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.pollfish:pollfish:+:googleplayRelease@aar'
implementation 'org.iban4j:iban4j:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
implementation project(':supportdifferentscreens')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.theoremreach:theoremreach:3.2.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.cleveroad:slidingtutorial:1.0.8'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
implementation 'com.tapr:tapresearch:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
//Arch
implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
//Appodeal
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' //for Inmobi
implementation name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar'
```

Comment: We are having the same issue over here. Has one found a solution? We thought maybe the problem were dagger2 - dagger1 incompatibility, but in your graddle build dagger is not included, so no clue